# Check if property from parent has changed

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, properties

I've created a new class that inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. Inside this class, I created another timer as property that is enabled with the timer of the parent class. The child-timer timer then reports back the time until the next parent-tick.

I would like to avoid having to use another method to start both timers.

Can I somehow check if the parent timer.enabled has been changed? The problem here is that if I start the parent timer, I have to wait for the `timer.Interval` until it ticks the first time. But I want the child timer to start with the parent timer to start reporting back the time of the first tick.

Here is what I've got so far.

```
public class LoopTimer : Timer {

    public DateTime? NextTickSchedule { get; set; }

    public LoopTimer() : base() {
        CountdownTimer.Interval = 1000;
        CountdownTimer.Tick += CountdownTimer_Tick;
        this.Tick += LoopTimer_Tick;
    }

    public LoopTimer(IContainer container) : base(container) {
        CountdownTimer.Interval = 1000;
    }

    private void LoopTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        OnTick();
    }

    private void OnTick() {
        NextTickSchedule = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(this.Interval);
        MinutesUntilNextTick = TimeUntilNextTick.ToString("mm\\:ss");
    }

    public void StartTimer() {
        this.Enabled = CountdownTimer.Enabled = true;
        OnTick();
    }

    public void StopTimer() {
        this.Enabled = CountdownTimer.Enabled = false;
        NextTickSchedule = null;
        MinutesUntilNextTick = "";
        TimeUntilNextTick = new TimeSpan();
    }

    #region Countdown Timer

    public Timer CountdownTimer { get; set; } = new Timer();
    public TimeSpan TimeUntilNextTick { get; set; } = new TimeSpan();
    public string MinutesUntilNextTick { get; set; } = "";

    private void CountdownTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (NextTickSchedule.HasValue) {
            TimeUntilNextTick = NextTickSchedule.Value - DateTime.Now;
            MinutesUntilNextTick = TimeUntilNextTick.ToString("mm\\:ss");
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: You can override `Enabled` property and raise an event. Then in the child/other control, subscribe for that event.

Comment: I was thinking about that as well but decided not to because in the .NET Reference Source there is a lot going on in the Enabled property which might break the Timer, not sure. I'll give it a try.

Comment: It depends to your implementation. When you just call base.Enabled getter and setter, then there is no chance to break the base class rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `Enabled` property and raise an event when enabled changes. Then in the child/other control, subscribe for that event:

```
public class MyTimer : Timer
{
    public event EventHandler EnabledChanged;
    public override bool Enabled
    {
        get { return base.Enabled; }
        set
        {
            base.Enabled = value;
            EnabledChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice! this works great. I didn't think about `base.Enabled` for properties. Much appreciate the quick help. 
However, an event wasn't needed. Used `set => base.Enabled = CountdownTimer.Enabled = value;` in the setter.

Comment: Great. Good idea. The event is useful when you don't have any idea about what the consumer may do. But based on what you are going to do, you don't need the event.